# ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8)

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-development

For study and fun I try to create my own altcoin.
I forked Litecoin, removed checkpoints, changed nTime, *pszTimestamp, noNce and hashed new hashes for genesis block in main net, testnet and regressiontest net.
The hardcoded assertions goes OK but when I start the deamon

```
./src/cryptoind
```

I get alwais the same result:

```
ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8) ... ActivateBestChainStep --> Failed!
```

Going deeper in the code the following statement always fails (main.cpp):

```
if (UintToArith256(hash) > bnTarget)
```

Seems like the genesis block does not respect the difficulty (PoW)

Someone faced the same issue? Thank you all

Comment: I met same problem. Have you solved? How?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the -reindex parameter solves the issue.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/8081

Comment: Welcome to BitcoinSE! Please note, the original question states that it is a fork of Litecoin.

Comment: Yes but the -reindex parameter still seems to solve the issue. I had made further explanation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828172/encountering-readblockfromdisk-errors-in-block-header-at-cblockdiskposnfile-0/48606397#48606397 I also am trying to create an altcoin and had stuck at the same ERROR message then applying -reindex parameter at least made it work up to a point where I begin to get Error -28 from rpc call which is said to be "Client is still warming up!" (whatever it means) at https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.15.0.1/src/rpc/protocol.h#L32L87.

Comment: Re-Hi to all, i've tried a lot of times with -reindex parameter, but i have the same issue. "ERROR: ReadBlockFromDisk: Errors in block header at CBlockDiskPos(nFile=0, nPos=8) ... ActivateBestChainStep --> Failed!"

Comment: Hello, thx for info. -reindex really take me next step. and now when I run ./xxxcoind -reindex,  it seems stop, debug.log says "potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer", do you know why and solution?

Comment: So I googled and added [ -connect=0 ] at last. Then again ReadBlockError occured. So I need to maybe actually mine genesis block inside the code. How? And where put that code? At chainparams.cpp's  before  [ assert(consensus.hashGenesisBlock  ]  line?